# How can I generate an image on my website based on user text input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-processing

*The last time I asked this question it was merged with another inaccurate question. To clarify, I want to have the website generate a brand new, consolidated image. Not overlay one element on another, but actually create one cohesive .png.*

The project I'm working on is a website that will generate an image based on book quotes. I have a series of input fields (Your name, Author, Book, Quote) and I want the user's input to be edited onto an image. The images are not uploaded by the user (it's randomly selected from a pre-determined list).

The next step of this project would be to automatically post the output image to social media, but I'm just trying to figure out how to process the image.

I'm new to web design, so my knowledge up to this point has been gained through Reddit and w3schools (amazing resource).

Something similar to the output I'm looking for: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyH19.png)

Comment: Something like http://fabricjs.com/ is probably what you'll need. A Canvas element can be rendered down to a PNG easily.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a direct answer, but you could look at Javascript and HTML5 Canvas to achieve this.

Example: https://chenmu10.github.io/memeGenerator/

You can also download the demo code at https://www.cssscript.com/responsive-meme-generator/ and check it out.

FYI I am not the owner of this project.